# Only administrator user create new users in Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created a user with devise gem and assign a Boolean field to indicate whether the user is an administrator.But I have not found any examples of how to make only the administrator user can register another user.

I created a UserController:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    before_action :is_admin?, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

   def new_user

   end

   def create

   end


  protected

  def is_admin?
    if !user_signed_in?
      redirect_to user_session_path
    elsif !((current_user.is? :admin) & (user_signed_in?))
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

and my routes file:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { 
        sessions: "user/sessions",
        confirmations: 'user/confirmations',
        passwords: 'user/passwords' }

  get 'users/new_user' => 'user#new_user', as: :new_user
  post 'users/create_user' => 'user#create', as: :create_user
```

but in my view new_user.html.erb displays this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#<Class:0x007efbcc054a78>:0x007efbe003f880>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is you're trying to render the devise registration, but `resource, devise_mapping...` has not been initialized in `new_user.html.erb`

Initialized these variables in `application_helper.rb` so it can be accessible anywhere in your view.

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and most idiomatic way to do what you want is to override the devise `registrations` controller, and add your `before_action` in your custom subclass. That way, you retain all of the devise "magic" while being able to customize who has access.

I will say that if authorization plays a large part in your application, you might consider adding a gem to manage user roles such as [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)